# How do I reference a static JS file in node_modules?

Tags: vue.js

I'm following this tutorial [Add Loading Indicators to Your Vue.js Application](https://scotch.io/tutorials/add-loading-indicators-to-your-vuejs-application) to add NProgress to my Vue app. In the tutorial, it adds the following code to `index.html`:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/nprogress@0.2.0/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/nprogress@0.2.0/nprogress.js"></script>
```

Due to security reasons, my organization prefers to install NProgress as a node module and reference that rather than using CDN. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `npm install nprogress --save`

Follow the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nprogress) for more information

Hope it helps.

Comment: I actually looked into this module but I didn't know if I could trust it. Did the creators of NProgress create this module?

Comment: Though not that popular I've used it in some of my projects, it's nice. Well, since you're working on your company's project it's only good to take precautions. I've updated the link to nprogress npm page